# @fontface code not displaying fonts correctly, only draws from local source

Tags: internet-explorer, webkit, font-face

I am having a pretty persistent @fontface issue, and I know I must be missing something simple. I have a test mockup [here](http://www.diacritica.pe/fontface.html).

Issue: text should be Tiemann Light but defaults to Times.

It works fine in webkit browsers, nothing else. I have really searched similar questions here and need it to display on Firefox, IE 9 webkit browsers and so forth. I am not sure what I am missing, I have tried all kinds of permutations, messing with syntax in various styles that I have seen posted, tried absolute font paths, relative font paths to no avail.

Thanks in advance,

David

The code is as follows:

```
<style>

@font-face {
font-family:Tiemann;
src: url(http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.eot);
src: url(http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
src: url(http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.woff) format("woff"),
src: url(http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/TiemannLight.ttf) format("truetype"),
src: url(http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.svg) format("svg");
}

span{
font-family:Tiemann;
font-size:14pt;
color:#376092;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<span>This should be in Tieman Light with Color. -- DIACRÍTICA  --  </span>

</body>
```

Comment: Not sure whether it's the root of the problem, but I'd get rid of the XHTML document type definition first. (`<style>` without a "type" attribute isn't valid XHTML as far as I remember)

Comment: Which IE version are you testing? Any notes in the F12 Tool's CONSOLE tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'Tiemann';
src: url('http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.eot');
src: url('http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/TiemannLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://www.diacritica.pe/fonts/tiemannlightwebfont.svg#Tiemann') format('svg');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Vinicius Santana for that tip. I pasted it in and it works. The syntax adjustments made here allowed the fonts to display properly across browsers and platforms. It seems to have had to do with the quotes. This has saved me an insane amount of guess and check permutation troubleshooting. Thanks so much.

Comment: All good man. I had the same problem a while ago. I'm happy that I could help.